# Ordering taxonomy output in this function

Tags: terms

I found (googled) this function which performs almost exactly as I need. Creating a link text structure (breadcrumb) of terms for a CPT i.e. Parent Category -> Child Category -> Grand Child Category

The only issue is the order is which it is output is slightly off - Child Category -> Parent Category -> Grand Child Category

I cant figure out from the code below how to order it correctly.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

rob

```
function get_the_term_list_breadcrumbs( $id = 0, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '', $breadcrumb_sep = ' &rarr; ' ) {
$terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );

if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) )
    return $terms;

if ( empty( $terms ) )
    return false;

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
    if ( is_wp_error( $link ) )
        return $link;

    // Find parents
    $names = array();
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
    if ( count( $ancestors ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $ancestors as $anc ) {
            $t = get_term( $anc, $taxonomy );
            $names[] = $t->name;
        }
    }
    $names[] = $term->name;
    $link_text = implode( $breadcrumb_sep, $names );

    $term_links[] = '<a href="' . $link . '" rel="tag">' . $link_text . '</a>';
}

$term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $term_links );

return $before . join( $sep, $term_links ) . $after;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_ancestors()` returns an array with the parent first, then the grandparent, etc. What you need to do change `get_ancestors()` to `array_reverse( get_ancestors() )`, so that you have the level of the parents descends, instead of ascending.

Comment: If this was the solution, mark the question as solved.